# bifurcations,bifurcation points and bifurcation diagram

Tags: bifurcation

For a real number $c$, define the one-parameter family $f_a(x)=(x-a)(2x-3a)+x+c$.

For what values of $c$ is there a bifurcation in this family?

Describe the bifurcations and list the bifurcation points $(a, x)$, and sketch the bifurcation diagram.

Comment: google "feigenbaum constants". This should be helpful.

Comment: please could you give me an answer for this problem?